# Data is displayed with different styles in the same column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am Working with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

All values in my table are displayed, after I have made an INSERT INTO in the column BA (NVARCHAR (31)), in order to fill in missing values. They are displayed in a different format than the already existing values.

I already tried ALTERING the column to a different datatype (float) but it did not help either.

I expect the output of for example '5001100016' instead of '5.0011e+009'

Thanks for your help, I am very new to SQL

Comment: Why are you using a string to store numeric values?  Try using `numeric`/`decimal`.

Comment: How are you displaying the values? Explain and include a screenshot.

Comment: @GordonLinoff when I try to convert the data type to numeric I get the Error message 'error converting data type to numeric' (thanks for the quick answer)

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for the answer, I will include a screenshot asap

Comment: Your column data type should be Numeric or Decimal from the start. If so, then *how* you are inserting the data is important (script, C#/Java, SSIS, etc.). If it's already Numeric/Decimal, and you are seeing the value with the e, then the interface/program that's retrieving the value is important.

Comment: @EzLo thanks, i just inserted everything into a new Table and it worked fine with Decimal.

Comment: I can't view that image, as it's blocked I'm afraid. Data is far better provided as `text`. As for your question (which is effectively) *"Why is the value `5001100016` being displaying as the **floating point** value `5.0011e+009`"* that much is obvious; you're using a floating point data type (`float`). if you don't want a floating point value, don't use a floating point data type. You have [several others to choose from](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/numeric-types?view=sql-server-ver15).